# What do diagonal matrices do in irreducible repns of SL$_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}_N := \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$.
For every $a \in \mathbb{Z}_N^\times$ put $R_a = \begin{pmatrix} a^{-1} & 0  \\ 0 & a\end{pmatrix}$ and also set $T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.
Let $\rho$ be a unitary, irreducible representation of SL$_2(\mathbb{Z}_N)$. I want to know "how" $\rho(R_A)$ looks like.

What I expect / have already observed:
For certain irreducible representations in the case that $N=p$ is an odd prime I observed the following: As $\rho$ is unitary, one can diagonalize $\rho(T)$ to get a basis
$$V = \oplus_{s \in \mathbb{Z}_p} V^{(s)}$$
where $\rho(T) v^{(s)} = e^{2 \pi i s/p} v^{(s)}$ for all $s \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.
Using some properties of the concrete representation I was looking at I was able to conclude that $\rho(R_a)$ maps $V^{(s)}$ bijectively into $V^{(a^2 s)}$ and that one can choose bases such that
  $$\rho(R_a) v^{(s)}_i = \pm v^{(a^2 s)}_i$$

---

### Question: Is it true (in the general case SL$_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$) that one can choose bases of the spaces $V^{(s)}$ such that $\rho(R_a)$ permutes the basis vectors?

---

If not, can one still say something about $\rho(R_a)$? I have the feeling that this action should be of a simple nature...

Does somebody know a database or program (possibly free/os) with which one can construct the irreducible representations of SL$_2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$ for small $N$ like $3,5,7,15$, etc. so that I can play around a bit?

cheers,

FW